# Using Node.js & NForce, Retrieve Records on Startup

Tags: node.js, rest, salesforce

I am attempting to modify this code:

https://github.com/jeffdonthemic/node-streaming-socketio/blob/master/app.js

So that as well as setting up the streaming, on startup it also performs a query to retrieve some records which are displayed to the user. I am attempting to place code like so:

```
var q = 'SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, BillingCity FROM Account';

sfdc.query({ query: q }, function(err, resp){

  if(!err && resp.records) {

    // do something with record, display to client
  }
});
```

After the connection and ouath have been set up, however, I am unsure where to place that code in the lifecycle of the main application (app.js). Also, I am unsure how to pass this record once I have it so that it can be displayed on the client side. I keep getting this error when placing this code at various places in app.js:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance_url' of undefined
```

Comment: I would add this to routes/index.js.
That route is what you see first and where you should have the records loaded.
Is that or add another route and call it using AJAX.

Comment: @geekymartian wouldn't I have to reinit the nforce connection and oauth settings then?

Comment: You can keep it global removing the `var` statement. Still, I think you need to perform the query from the client side, that 'instance_url' is thrown by express and may be because the query is asynchronous.